# Pygame - first person shooter "look" with mouse

Tags: python, mouse, pygame, pyopengl

I am not writing a game but a scientific renderer using Pygame. I'd like the controls to work just like in a first-person shooter, so that a user can navigate using a familiar set of controls.

I have tried to write the code to have the same properties as the 'look' feature in e.g. Skyrim or Half-Life but the mouse doesn't move the cursor - it lets you look around and around, in infinite circles. Clicking should have no effect.

**The first attempt for the controls:**

(code inside a game loop)

```py
delta_y, delta_x = pygame.mouse.get_rel()
rotation_direction.x = float(delta_x)
rotation_direction.y = float(delta_y)
```

*(don't ask me why, but y and x need to be reversed like this to get the expected look directions; must be something to do with the camera transform implementation, which [isn't mine](http://www.willmcgugan.com/blog/tech/2007/6/4/opengl-sample-code-for-pygame/).)*

This, however, leads to a cursor sitting on top of the window, and when the cursor gets to the edge of the screen the window stops rotating; i.e. the code is reporting the actual position on the screen.

I tried to 'reset' the mouse position every game loop (and, incidentally, hide the mouse):

```py
pygame.mouse.set_pos([150, 150])
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
```

But this generates a symmetrical 'move back to start' delta in the next loop, meaning that you couldn't 'look' anywhere.

To summarize, I want to:

- detect actual mouse motion reported from the device
- not move/show any OS cursor
- not clip at the 'edge of a screen'

What is the best way to do this, using Pygame or other Python hacks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html :

If the mouse cursor is hidden, **and input is grabbed to the current display** the mouse will enter a virtual input mode, where the relative movements of the mouse will never be stopped by the borders of the screen. See the functions `pygame.mouse.set_visible` - hide or show the mouse cursor and `pygame.event.set_grab` ([docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.set_grab)) - control the sharing of input devices with other applications to get this configured.

Comment: In other words, also call pygame.event.set_grab(True)

Comment: Aha, I looked in the docs for a mouse capture function but couldn't find it, hence the suggestion in my answer.

Comment: On my computer the order mattered, grabbing then hiding the mouse still got caught on the edges, whereas grabbing then hiding works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `pygame.mouse.get_rel()` once more immediately after the `set_pos` call to 'throw away' whatever relative movement the `set_pos` call has performed.

Comment: I did think about this after I'd posted the question, but @Ofir's answer is much simpler. Thanks!

Comment: His answer is also the 'proper' way. :)

Comment: I stopped short of saying that, as it sounded a bit mean! but yes, I suppose it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using pyOpenGL, try `gluLookAt()` example: [How do I use gluLookAt properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380100/how-do-i-use-glulookat-properly)

Comment: While this doesn't strictly answer the question (which is about mouse events capture,) `gluLookAt` is something I hadn't seen before, and looks very relevant to anyone trying to solve this problem - in my case, it would allow me to avoid using some python code (much slower) to do the same thing by hand. Thanks for the heads up! :)