# Rotate camera around a textured polygon while looking at it - OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, image-processing, camera, textures

I have a simple textured polygon with a bitmap image texture on it.

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureId);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    //Front face

    glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-BOX_SIZE / 2, -BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(BOX_SIZE / 2, -BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2);

    glEnd();
```

I want to rotate around the object so it will face directly at me.
how can I change the position of the camera?

Comment: You can use [gluLookAt](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) function.

Comment: Im very new to opengl and I dont know how to use glulookat properly. can you give me a help with that?

Comment: Hopefully my answer clears it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OpenGL you can use [gluLookAt](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) function to move in space.

Think of the camera as a point in space.
The first 3 parameters determinate your position.
Next 3 parameters determinate another point in space, where the camera will look.

Here I've composed a picture: (The cartoon character is taken from [here](http://toonjamstudios.com/wp-content/gallery/character-designs/burfield-cartoon-3.png))
[image: How gluLookAt works]

In the picture you can see a man standing in position pos.x, pos.y, pos.z looking at some point (the red dot) look.x, look.y, look.z;

The upVec is just a vector determinating a direction of your head.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3380207/3421618) post [Carlos Scheidegger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221007/carlos-scheidegger) briefly explains what the upVec does:

> The intuition behind the "up" vector in gluLookAt is simple: Look at
> anything. Now tilt your head 90 degrees. Where you are hasn't changed,
> the direction you're looking at hasn't changed, but the image in your
> retina clearly has. What's the difference? Where the top of your head
> is pointing to. That's the up vector.

In most cases, you want to set the upVec to (0,1,0) since that's the direction of your head in most cases.